# Incomplete type 'std::tuple_size' used in nested name specifier

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, tuple

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>

template <typename T, std::size_t... I>
std::ostream& printTupleImp(std::ostream& os, const T& tp, std::index_sequence<I...>) {
    std::size_t index = 0;
    const auto printElem = [&index, &os](const auto& x) {
        if (index++ > 0) 
            os << ", ";
        os << x;
    };

    os << "(";
    (printElem(std::get<I>(tp)), ...);
    os << ")";

    return os;
}

template <typename T, std::size_t Size = std::tuple_size_v<T>>
std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& os, const T& tp) {
    return printTupleImp(os, tp, std::make_index_sequence<Size>{}); 
}

int main() {
    std::cout << std::tuple{1, 2., "3"} << '\n';
}
```

Почему программа для печати тапла [не компилируется](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:4,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:4,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:4,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:4),source:%27%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%23include+%3Ctuple%3E%0A%23include+%3Cutility%3E%0A%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename+T,+std::size_t...+I%3E%0Astd::ostream%26+printTupleImp(std::ostream%26+os,+const+T%26+tp,+std::index_sequence%3CI...%3E)+%7B%0A%09std::size_t+index+%3D+0%3B%0A++++const+auto+printElem+%3D+%5B%26index,+%26os%5D(const+auto%26+x)+%7B%0A%09%09if+(index%2B%2B+%3E+0)+%0A++++++++++++os+%3C%3C+%22,+%22%3B%0A%09%09os+%3C%3C+x%3B%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A++++os+%3C%3C+%22(%22%3B%0A++++(printElem(std::get%3CI%3E(tp)),+...)%3B%0A++++os+%3C%3C+%22)%22%3B%0A%0A++++return+os%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename+T,+std::size_t+Size+%3D+std::tuple_size_v%3CT%3E%3E%0Astd::ostream%26+operator+%3C%3C(std::ostream%26+os,+const+T%26+tp)+%7B%0A++++return+printTupleImp(os,+tp,+std::make_index_sequence%3CSize%3E%7B%7D)%3B+%0A%7D%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++++std::cout+%3C%3C+std::tuple%7B1,+2.,+%223%22%7D+%3C%3C+!%27%5Cn!%27%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:executor,i:(argsPanelShown:%271%27,compilationPanelShown:%270%27,compiler:gsnapshot,compilerOutShown:%270%27,execArgs:%27%27,execStdin:%27%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B20%27,source:1,stdinPanelShown:%271%27,tree:%271%27,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Executor+x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)?

> error: incomplete type 'std::tuple_size' used in nested name
> specifier

Comment: потому что Ваш operator<< перекрывает все остальное и оно пытается им распечатать и '\n'. Попробуйте просто распечатать `std::cout << '\n';`

Comment: [Код похоже отсюда](https://www.cppstories.com/2022/sfinea-immediate-context/)? Там разве не было объяснения?

Answer (score 1):

`std::tuple_size_v<T>` - не *[SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae)-friendly*, т.е. попытка передать в него неправильный тип приводит сразу к ошибке компиляции, а не к такой ошибке, которую можно остановить SFINAE.

Судя по ошибке, компилятор пытается вызвать ваш `operator<<` на `char` (видимо `\n`?), с которым, конечно, `tuple_size` работать не умеет.

Решение - заменить `std::tuple_size_v<T>` на `std::tuple_size<T>::value`, который является SFINAE-friendly.

Тогда попытка сделать `tuple_size<char>` будет остановлена SFINAE, и будет вызван следующий подходящий `operator<<` для `char` - стандартный.

---

Но вообще, такая перегрузка оператора - плохая идея. Их нужно перегружать в том же неймспейсе, что и один из параметров - чтобы [ADL](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) работал.

Например, следующий код не соберется с вашим оператором (даже с исправленным):

```
namespace NS
{
    struct A {};
    void operator<<(A, A) {}

    void foo()
    {
        std::cout << std::tuple{1, 2., "3"} << '\n';
    }
}
```

Тут бы помогло задвинуть ваш `<<` в `namespace std`, но это запрещено.

Answer (score 1):

Не компилируется т.к. ваша реализация оператора `<<` случайно вызывается также для `'\n'` символа, который конечно не будет работать т.к. не является тьюплом.

Это легко исправляется, если указать вторым аргументом конкретно `std::tuple`, как я сделал ниже.

В моей версии можно даже упростить и вместо `tuple_size_v` использовать просто `std::size_t Size = sizeof...(Args)`. Либо вообще убрать `Size` и просто в коде сделать `std::index_sequence_for<Args...>{}` вместо `std::make_index_sequence<Size>{}`.

[Попробовать онлайн!](https://godbolt.org/z/9cTMq8G3q)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>

template <typename T, std::size_t... I>
std::ostream& printTupleImp(std::ostream& os, const T& tp, std::index_sequence<I...>) {
    std::size_t index = 0;
    const auto printElem = [&index, &os](const auto& x) {
        if (index++ > 0) 
            os << ", ";
        os << x;
    };

    os << "(";
    (printElem(std::get<I>(tp)), ...);
    os << ")";

    return os;
}

template <typename ... Args, std::size_t Size = std::tuple_size_v<std::tuple<Args...>>>
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const std::tuple<Args...> & tp) {
    return printTupleImp(os, tp, std::make_index_sequence<Size>{}); 
}

int main() {
    std::cout << std::tuple{1, 2., "3"} << '\n';
}
```

Вывод:

```
(1, 2, 3)
```

---

Решил учесть [замечание](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1393849/incomplete-type-stdtuple-size-used-in-nested-name-specifier/1393964#comment2477469_1393964) от @HolyBlackCat, и реализовать поддержку не только `std::tuple`, но и `std::array` и `std::pair`. Сделал это через оператор [requires](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints) (а не [SFINAE](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SFINAE)):

[Попробовать онлайн!](https://godbolt.org/z/KhT919Wcq)

```cpp
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>
#include <array>

template <typename T, std::size_t... I>
std::ostream& printTupleImp(std::ostream& os, const T& tp, std::index_sequence<I...>) {
    std::size_t index = 0;
    const auto printElem = [&index, &os](const auto& x) {
        if (index++ > 0) 
            os << ", ";
        os << x;
    };

    os << std::boolalpha << "(";
    (printElem(std::get<I>(tp)), ...);
    os << ")";

    return os;
}

template <typename T> struct IsTuple : std::false_type {};
template <typename ... Args> struct IsTuple<std::tuple<Args...>> : std::true_type {};

template <typename T> struct IsArray : std::false_type {};
template <typename T, std::size_t Size> struct IsArray<std::array<T, Size>> : std::true_type {};

template <typename T> struct IsPair : std::false_type {};
template <typename A, typename B> struct IsPair<std::pair<A, B>> : std::true_type {};

template <typename T>
    requires IsTuple<T>::value || IsArray<T>::value || IsPair<T>::value
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const T & tp) {
    std::size_t constexpr Size = std::tuple_size_v<std::decay_t<T>>;
    return printTupleImp(os, tp, std::make_index_sequence<Size>{}); 
}

int main() {
    std::cout
        << std::tuple{true, 2., "str"} << '\n'
        << std::array{4, 5, 6} << '\n'
        << std::pair{false, 'c'} << '\n'
    ;
}
```

Вывод:

```
(true, 2, str)
(4, 5, 6)
(false, c)
```

Напомню что вместо:

```cpp
template <typename T>
    requires IsTuple<T>::value || IsArray<T>::value || IsPair<T>::value
```

можно использовать:

[Посмотреть онлайн!](https://godbolt.org/z/K8GW1o51G)

```cpp
template <typename T, typename Enable = std::enable_if_t<
    IsTuple<T>::value || IsArray<T>::value || IsPair<T>::value>>
```

Comment: Такой `operator<<` не работает для `std::pair`, `std::array`. Не знаю, хорошо это или плохо.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Решил учесть ваше замечание про pair/array и дополнил мой ответ второй частью, где реализовал поддержку pair/array в стиле концептов и `requires`.

Comment: Я имел в виду, что код в вопросе уже поддерживает все эти типы (если не учитывать ошибку, которую я исправил в ответе), а исправление, которое вы предложили в оригинальном ответе, эту поддержку убирает. Не обязательно проверять каждый тип отдельно, можно просто приложить SFINAE к `tuple_size`.